# Передача данных из Activity в ListFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так: пытаюсь передать заполненный Array  из Activity в ListFragment, который будет использоваться в ArrayAdepter для отображения списка, но когда вытаскиваю этот массив из arguments, он оказывается null(Проверял с помощью другого массива, расположенного в MainFragment).

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
            android:name="com.e.myapplication9.MainFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.e.myapplication9

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var arr: Array<String> = arrayOf("Example")
    val mainFragment = MainFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainFragment.arguments?.putStringArray("arr",arr)
    }
}
```

MainFragment:

```
package com.e.myapplication9

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment

class MainFragment: ListFragment() {

    private var arr = arguments?.getStringArray("arr")
    var no: Array<String> = arrayOf("arr is null")


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        if(arr != null)
            listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr!!)
        else listAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, no)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи данных из Activity в Fragment нужно использовать Bundle:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putStringArrayList();("key", array)
fragment.arguments = bundle
```

В Fragment в методе onCreateView или onActivityCreated принимаем данные из Activity:

```
val array = arguments?.getStringArrayList("key")
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает, а если нужно передать массив объектов?(Передача также между Activity и ListFragment)

Answer (score 1):

Вот это никуда не годится.

```
private var arr = arguments?.getStringArray("arr")
```

Потому что отрабатывает в конструкторе, как результат -- отсутствие данных.
Как вариант для Kotlin, сделайте поле `lateinit`.

И еще. Зачем создаете фрагмент в коде, если он у вас создается в разметке?
Вот этот фрагмент

```
val mainFragment = MainFragment()
```

в результате "зависает". Он создан, но не присоединен к активити.
А тот, что на экране, данных не получает.